# C++ setting father node in a tree

Tags: c++, tree

I have the following class:

```
class Node
{
  private:   
     Node* leftChild;
     Node* rightChild;
     Node* father;   
  public:   
     Node() { leftChild = rightChild = father = NULL; };     
     Node* getLeftChild() { return leftChild; };
     Node* getRightChild() { return rightChild; };
     Node* getFather() { return father; }
     void setRightChild(Node* child) { rightChild = child; }
     void setLeftChild(Node* child) { leftChild = child; };
     void setFather(Node* f) { father = f; };   
};
```

I would set also the father node when setting the left child and the right child. I try:

```
void setLeftChild(Node* child)
{
  leftChild = child;
  child->setFather(this);
};    

Node* node = new Node();
Node* node2 = new Node();

node->setLeftChild(node2);
```

and due to the wrong use of this, I receive a random error. How I should set the function `setLeftChild()` and `setRightChild()` ?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not mother node? That's sexist. That's why we call it parent. *triggered*

Comment: Please give details of the error

Comment: Have you qualifed that function correctly or is a global rather than a class member?

Comment: how about checking if the child is 'this' in the first place ? At least that would prevent doing stupid things.

Comment: In this case, a node can have itself as child (it is an exercise). The error is that the program is stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, your

```
node->setLeftChild(node);
```

will produce nonsense. You must either write valid code or (at least in DEBUG mode) guard against such nonsense

```
void setLeftChild(Node* child)
{
  if(child==this)
    throw std::runtime_error("node cannot be its own child");
  leftChild = child;
  child->setFather(this);
};
```

---

Another idea is to make `father` a immutable member that has to be provided at construction (and equals `nullptr` only for the root node), i.e.

```
struct Node
{
  Node*const father;      // immutable, so might as well be public
  Node(Node*f) : father(f) {}
  Node*MakeLeftChild()    // create left child and return it
  {
    if(!leftChild)
      leftChild = new Node(this);
    return leftChild;
  }
  Node*MakeRightChild()   // create right child and return it
  {
    if(!rightChild)
      rightChild = new Node(this);
    return rightChild;
  }
private:
  Node*leftChild=nullptr;   // defaults to having no children
  Node*rightChild=nullptr;
};

auto root = new Node(nullptr);
auto node = root->MakeLeftChild();
node = node->MakeRightChild();
```

Comment: if i write child->setFather(this); the program get stuck.